# SQL Selecting rows with multiple values

Tags: sql, select

I have these 2 tables:

Table `SW_ITEM`:

```
ID  SWID  ITEM_ID
1    1      99
2    2      99
3    5      99
4    2      100
5    1      100
6    1      101
7    2      102
```

Table `ITEM`:

```
  ID   FILENAME
  99      abc
  100     def
  101     geh
  102     ijk
```

column `ITEM_ID` is a foreign key to the column `ID` of table `ITEM`.

So I want all filenames which have the SWID "1" AND "2" (that would be ITEMID 99 and 100, so their filenames are "abc" and "def")

Here I have to say that it is possible that `ITEM_ID` has more than one entry with the same SWID, so I cannot use this SQL:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID FROM SW_ITEM
WHERE SWID  IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY ITEM_ID
HAVING COUNT(ITEM_ID) = 2
```

So is there any other possibility to get all entries which have the SWID 1 and 2 (creating a join for every SWID is also not an option - because with many entries it would be really slow)

Kind regards

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use `DISTINCT` in `COUNT` and count `SWID` instead of `ITEM_ID`:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID FROM SW_ITEM
WHERE  SWID IN (1,2) 
GROUP  BY ITEM_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SWID) = 2;
```

Please checkout [**this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c25d2/3).

To retrieve all filenames, try:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, FILENAME
FROM   ITEM JOIN SW_ITEM ON ITEM.ID = SW_ITEM.ITEM_ID
WHERE  SWID IN (1,2) 
GROUP  BY ITEM_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SWID) = 2;
```

#### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c25d2/7)

Comment: when i use distinct a get an empty result (i musst say that this is a quite unexpected result ;) )

Comment: @semirrahic You should count `DISTINCT SWID` instead of `ITEM_ID`; Please checkout the demo.

Comment: when trying the demo it works fine :) but when i try it with my SQL i still get an empty result. Maybe it has something to do with the sql version - i am using firebird

Comment: @semirrahic Did you change `COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM_ID)` into `COUNT(DISTINCT SWID)`?

Answer (score 1):

I have a little different problem where I have to **find a person with multiple entries in the same table based on email** for that the above solution didn't work for me. You can try using the following,

```
SELECT person_id, 
(ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY pers_email ORDER BY pers_name) person_count  
from pers_table
WHERE person_count > 2;
```

Try this hope it works :)